# Place checked checkbox array in sql statement

Tags: php, arrays

I am making a checkbox filter, I need to place the associative array chosen from the chekboxes in the sql statement so that in this case it shows the results of these two categories but I have not yet been able to achieve it if you can help me thanks

```
$array_category = array(
"1" => "design",
"2" => "food",
```

);

```
if ($sentence= $db->query("SELECT * FROM post WHERE state = 1  AND category IN ".implode(",", $array_category).")"){
```

Comment: It should be ```"SELECT * FROM post WHERE state = 1  AND category IN ('".implode("','", $array_category)."')"```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
"SELECT * FROM post WHERE state = 1  AND category IN ('".implode("','", $array_category)."')"
```

Update 1:
For sql injection

```
\DB::select(\DB::raw("SELECT * FROM post WHERE state = 1 AND category IN (" . str_repeat("?,",count($array_category)-1) . "?" . ")"), $array_category)
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: I just only correct Razer 's sql syntax error

Comment: Right, but apparently the OP is unaware of that as well.